# Group of all permutations of $\mathbb N$ that don't change the limit of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, group-theory, convergence-divergence, permutations, absolute-convergence

Clearly all bijections functions $\varphi : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ form a group, let's call it $S(\mathbb N)$. Now let's define $H \subset S(\mathbb N)$ to be the set of all elements $\varphi \in S(\mathbb N)$ such that for every real valued sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ for which
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$
converges we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{\varphi(n)}.$$
Clearly $H$ forms a proper subgroup of $S(\mathbb N)$. For fixed $n \in \mathbb N$ the group $S_n$ is a subgroup of $H$. But this is not everything. For example the map
$$
\varphi(n) := n+(-1)^{n+1}
$$
is also in $H$ without being a finite permuation.

**Question 1**: Does the group $H$ have a special name? Is it mentioned somewhere in literature?

**Question 2**: Is $H$ simply the group of all "infinite products of disjoint cycles"?

Comment: Minor suggestion: There is no need for the summation, as the sequence $b_n:=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ is again a real valued sequence, and conversely every real valued sequence $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ is of the form $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ for the real valued sequence $a_n:=b_n-b_{n-1}$, starting with $a_1=b_1$.

Comment: My guess was arbitrary products of finite cycles. Is there an infinite cycle that does not change the values of series?

Comment: Why is it clear that $H$ is a *proper* subgroup of $S(\Bbb{N})$?

Comment: @Servaes Because there are convergent series which don't converge absolutely. Such series can be premuted to attain every limit you want. Google Riemann series theorem.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3678/42969.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1383730/42969.

Comment: On Math Overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/a/214777/116247.

Comment: @MartinR So my $H$ isn't even a group because it is not closed under inversion?